# How can I send a request using the HTTP Options method with HTTPClient (Java 11)?

Tags: java, http, http-method, java-http-client

As the title says, I would like to know how to send an HTTP request using HTTPClient with the OPTIONS method in Java. I have looked at the HTTP methods that can be used (GET, POST, PUT and DELETE) and I have not seen this option. 
An example of a GET/POST request with HTTPClient would be like this:

```java
String uri = "https://www.stackoverflow.com/"
HttpRequest.Builder preRequest=null;

// EXAMPLE OF GET REQUEST
preRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
.uri(URI.create( uri ))
.GET();

// EXAMPLE OF POST REQUEST
preRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
.uri(URI.create( uri ))
.POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(req.getBody()));  // "req" is an object of a class made by me, it does not matter in this context
```

In case it can't be used (which would seem extremely rare to me), what alternative can I use?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: "with the OPTIONS method" - What *OPTIONS method*?

Comment: I mean Http OPTIONS Method [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpRequest.Builder` has a `.method​(String method, HttpRequest.BodyPublisher bodyPublisher)` method which allows you to set a different HTTP method than the defined shortcuts such as `.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublisher bodyPublisher)`.

> `HttpRequest.Builder`
> `method​(String method, HttpRequest.BodyPublisher bodyPublisher)`
>
> Sets the request method and request body of this builder to the given values.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#method()

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm! +1 saved for when I have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

As said `HttpRequest.Builder` has a `.method​(String method, HttpRequest.BodyPublisher bodyPublisher)` that let you configure your method.

This is an example for `OPTIONS` method

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                 .method("OPTIONS", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                                 .uri(URI.create("http://localhost/api"))
                                 .build();
```